# Windows 8.1 taskbar application menu is glitched

Tags: operating-system, windows-8.1

Whenever I right click any application on the taskbar to get to its menu the background of the menu is black instead of white and icons are big and not positioned correctly.
I've tried restarting and it didn't help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVHLb.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way to fix this is to do a PC Refresh or an Automatic Repair may also work.

Here's some instructions on how to do so http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc